--rebase-merges without executing no-op picks from side branches
I'm developing a feature branch. During its history it grows a dependency on some other stable, public feature branch so I merge that feature into my branch[1]. History looks like this:
* a7d8dd1 - (HEAD -> feature) feature commit 2 (1 second ago) <Brendan Jackman>
*   65f4da1 - Merge branch 'dependency' into feature (7 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
|\  
| * b317496 - (dependency) dependency commit 2 (29 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
| * edd75a6 - dependency commit 1 (30 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
* | 4f8927c - feature commit 1 (11 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
|/  
* ec4a119 - (main) hello (57 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>

Now I discover a bug in feature commit 1. I haven't shared this code at all yet so I don't want to just fix this with a new commit at feature, I want to amend the buggy commit, so I want an outcome like this:
* cff3533 - (HEAD -> feature) feature commit 2 (1 second ago) <Brendan Jackman>
*   fc6ee02 - Merge branch 'dependency' into feature (1 second ago) <Brendan Jackman>
|\  
| * b317496 - (dependency) dependency commit 2 (4 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>
| * edd75a6 - dependency commit 1 (4 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>
* | 2d8c8da - feature commit 1 (FIXED) (6 seconds ago) <Brendan Jackman>
|/  
* ec4a119 - (main) hello (5 minutes ago) <Brendan Jackman>

Note that the 2nd parent of my new merge commit is the same as before, this is important because dependency is a published branch.
It turns out that git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges does indeed produce this eventual outcome. However, along the way, it performs a checkout of the history of dependency. The rebase-todo looks like this:
label onto

# Branch dependency
reset onto
pick edd75a6 dependency commit 1 # empty
pick b317496 dependency commit 2 # empty
update-ref refs/heads/dependency

label dependency

reset onto
pick 4f8927c feature commit 1 # empty
merge -C 65f4da1 dependency # Merge branch 'dependency' into feature
pick a7d8dd1 feature commit 2 # empty

For the toy example in this question, that's harmless, but in real life my dependency branch is huge and cannot be checked out without a git clean -fdx due to untracked files getting overwritten. So this is very slow and painful.
Now, the rebase-todo language does actually support what I wanna do:
pick 4f8927c feature commit 1 # empty
merge -C 65f4da1 dependency # Merge branch 'dependency' into feature
pick a7d8dd1 feature commit 2 # empty

But it's pretty annoying to have to dig into the git-rebase-todo (which is enormous in real life) and edit it every time I have to amend a commit. Is there a shortcut to generate that target history?
[1] Yes. This is horrible. But, that's how things work in the project I'm contributing to.

" I haven't shared this code at all yet so I don't want to just fix this with a new commit at feature, I want to amend the buggy commit"  Premature cleansing of commits.  When they conflict, worry about the commit messages when you squash / rebase / merge to main, and focus on efficiency of workflow when your work is still in flight.  In your case I would absolutely create a new commit.  Amending the first one does nothing but introduce a bunch of extra work.

"During its history it grows a dependency on some other stable, public feature branch so I merge that feature into my branch" if it's stable and public it should be in the integration branch.  "that's how things work in the project I'm contributing to." well, maybe so, but decisions have consequences.  If your project contributors insist on doing it the high friction way, then yeah, you'll be feeling a lot of heat.

About Yes. This is horrible. ABSOLUTELY NOT. This is precisely how it should be done. Others would suggest to merge the entire integration that already contains the feature branch. Or to rebase on top of it. NO! THAT is horrible.

I wonder if there's a flaw in the premise of this question. You say "It turns out that git rebase --interactive --rebase-merges does indeed produce this eventual outcome." So then what's the problem? The next sentence, "However, along the way, it rebuilds the history of dependency." seems to imply you believe the dependency commit IDs are changing, but based on what I'm looking at they shouldn't be.

Re: my previous comment- did the commit IDs on the dependency graph actually change or not in this example?

OK thanks for the input everyone. I already explained that I disapprove of the workflow, I don't have the influence to change it. If you can't provide input on the actual question just say "you're doing it wrong". Shall I rewrite it in Rust?

@Brendan note my comments/question are unrelated to the first 3 comments. I suspect that you're assuming since the commits appear in the rebase TODO list that they will be rewritten and modified, but that's not necessarily the case. In other words, I'm suggesting you don't have to search through the TODO list to delete the lines showing commits in the dependency branch. The result would be the same whether you delete those lines or leave them.

I"m trying to imagine how your workflow could be more needlessly convoluted, and failing. Your feature branch is unpublished, rebase it on its discovered dependency and fix what needs fixing. edit: don't bother preserving the merge, it's in unpublished work, it's not helpful, so lose it.

TTT - sorry your comment was indeed valid, I was too enraged by the noise commenters to mentally engage with it! Yes you're right, the commit IDs are not changing. IIUC this is because Git identifies nothing has changed when executing all of the pick items, so it doesn't actually create new commits. However, it still goes through the rigmarole of checking out each individual commit in the history, and that's the problem I'm facing. Does that make sense?

(Sorry I also can't help engaging with the noise comments, it's too enraging. jthill and others, you know nothing about the context of this workflow, you know nothing of the constraints that led to it, you know nothing of the tradeoffs being made here. AND ALSO, I've ALREADY TWICE ACKNOWLDEGED that I am opposed to it and would prefer to change it but am not empowered to do so. So you are contributing nothing at all to the conversation by telling me to change my workflow. Please butt out if you have nothing to say about the actual question)

Oh although I should also clarify: because of the way this project works (to do with being an enormously complex downstream of an enormously complex open-source project), I cannot rebase my local branch on top of the feature branch. There is a concrete need for the history of my branch to contain the merge.

Oh one more thing, a workaround that is good for my use case: While you're developing, put the merge commit at the base of the feature branch. Then you just don't encounter it at all while doing git rebase -i. Once the branch is all cleaned up and ready to be published, then just re-order the merge commit so it appears in the "correct" part of the history to record where the dependency arose.

@TTT Even though --rebase-merges includes the dependency commits in the TODO list, they are not changed. However, as part of the process, all of them are also actually checked out, and as was said in the question, this conflicts with untracked files.

The only workaround that I know of is to edit the TODO list: Remove all commits of the dependency branch (including the reset onto at its beginning) and edit the merge instruction to mention the tip of the dependency branch instead of dependency.

Ah... Got it. I think I was thrown off by "leave 2nd parent alone" and "cannot be rewritten", because from the POV of the commit IDs, the 2nd parent is left alone and is not rewritten. But the actual problem is solely the checkout during the rebase. I think this is a good question. I suspect the DVs were out in the weeds a bit as seen in the side discussions. I'm going to edit for clarity. (Also, FYI, you need to tag people with "@TTT" so it notifies us. I missed your comment to me until now.)

@j6t if the label isn't defined in the pick list Git looks it up as a ref, you can just delete the side-branch paragraph and merge -C 2a4cf1 dependency will merge dependency as it was when the command started (probably at 2a4cf1)

@jthill That's what I wanted to say. BTW, 2a4cf1 is the merge commit in the to-be-rewritten history, not the tip of the side branch (dependency). This -C 2a4cf1 tells Git which commit message and author date to use for the rewritten merge commit.

@j6t whoops. Right. So, probably not at 2a4cf1, instead it's 2a4cf1^2. Thanks.

Remove the instructions you left as no-ops from the pick list.
The rebase-todo pick list is instructions for creating new history on an arbitrary base, the "label onto" is wherever you're basing your new history.
If you do a no-op interactive rebase Git will present you with a todo list that's entirely no-op picks.
(edit: I see now that at the end of your question you say you already know this, and what you really want is to have Git automatically elide pick sequences in your edited todo list that it could prove must be picking unaltered commits onto their unaltered existing bases. The only answer to that is "no", it's doesn't try to reason about your instructions, it's just following them. What you're asking for involves not just remembering what's happened so far but also looking ahead at what's going to happen next.)
You can edit or reword or reorder the presented instructions any way you want. Turns out you don't want to alter the merged side branch at all, you just want to re-merge it as-is.
So take the resets and picks and relabels that you don't need, the ones that you know are still no-ops without any effect, out of the todo list.
#!/bin/sh
# put this in your path as e.g. git-fixup-only-simple-rebase and you can then 
# git fix<TAB> and run that, it'll apply a single commit --fixup update
# to your first-parent history if no other refs are affected, preserving
# merges from other (unaffected) branches. Give a `-e` to check the picklist.

. git-sh-setup
require_clean_work_tree

echo=:
while getopts exv opt; do case $opt in
e) echo=echo ;;     x) set -x; setx=x$setx ;;   v) set -v; setx=v$setx ;;
esac; done
# -e to write rather than vet and rebase with the reduced picklist
if test $echo = echo; then shift $((OPTIND-1)); exec >"${1:-/dev/tty}"; fi

read -r fixup verb subject <<EOD
$(git log --first-parent --pretty=%H\ %s -1 --grep '^\(fixup\|amend\|squash\)! ')
EOD
test -z $fixup && die "*** couldn't find autosquashable order in first-parent history"

target=$(git rev-parse -q --verify "$fixup^^{/$subject}" || git rev-parse -q --verify "$subject") || die "*** couldn't find fixup commit${subject:+ $subject}"
since=$((`git log --no-walk --pretty=%ct $target`-86400))
refs=$(git -c log.decorate=full log --all --since=@$since --pretty=%D \
    | sed -E 's,HEAD -> |tag: ,,g;s/, | -> /\n/g' \
    | git for-each-ref --stdin --contains $target --format="%(refname:short)")
refs=${refs:-$(git rev-parse HEAD)}

test $(printf %s "$refs" | wc -w) -eq 1 || die "*** multiple affected refs: $(echo $refs)"
_=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD) || die "*** fixup affects ref $refs that isn't HEAD"

while read commit parents; do
    eval "seen${parents%% *}=\$((seen${parents%% *}+1))"
    if eval test x2 = x\$seen${parents%% *}; then die "*** ancestry path to $target contains branches"; fi
    csub=$(git log --no-walk --pretty=%s $commit)

    if test $commit != $fixup; then case $parents in
    *\ *\ *) die "*** $0 haven't learned to handle octopus-merge" ;;
    *\ *)   $echo merge -C $commit $commit^2 \# $csub ;;
    *)  $echo pick $commit $csub
    esac; fi

    if test $commit = $target; then case $verb in 
    amend!) $echo fixup -C $fixup $csub ;;
    *)  $echo ${verb%!} $fixup $verb $subject
    esac; fi
done <<EOD
$(git rev-list --parents --reverse --ancestry-path=$target $target^! $refs)
EOD
if test $echo = :; then GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=$0\ -e$setx git rebase -ir $target^; fi


Thanks this does indeed work, the only extra detail is: in my example, the merge -C 65f4da1 dependency step just works. However in general you also have to rewrite that instruction, because dependency is actually a reference to a mark step in the rebade-todo, not a branch name. In my simple example the marks exactly match the name of the branch but this is not true in general, git sometimes generates new names for the mark references. So you have to rewrite it to refer to the branch name instead since you deleted the mark steps.

@Brendan yup. Just finished banging on a picklist generator that handles the simplest case, an --autosquashable commit in first-parent history of the checked-out branch that affects only that branch and doesn't require flattening any merges, it'll insert your dependency merges correctly.

You can see the picklist it'll generate with git fixup-only-simple-rebase -e /dev/tty, leave off the option and arg and it'll run the rebase that uses that picklist.

@Brendan got some sleep and started hammering out bugged cases, see if this does it for you now.

@Brendan fixed it so it works with dash, debian family's default shell (so ubuntu, which I think is the wsl default).

@Brendan last unsolicited comment: i made it run much, much faster on long histories and I think I made reword work properly, no reply needed unless you're interested in further changes

Wow thanks, this is very generous with your time, I did not expect someone to write me a custom solution!
